How I can create a shorter and short-lived token in a password Broker?
I am developing a rest api where a user will need to update its password.
So far I am sending the password reset token like this:
public function sendPasswordResetEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:api_users,email'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }

        $broker =  Password::broker('api_users');
        $user  = $broker->getUser(['email'=>$request->get('email')]);
        $token = $broker->createToken($user);

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new APIUSerPasswordResetToken($token));
        return response()->json(['msg'=>"Σας αποστείλαμε το token δια μέσω email"],202);
    }

And I configured the broker like this (file auth.php):
'passwords' => [
      
      'api_users'=>[
          'provider' => 'api_users',
          'table' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_TOKEN_TABLE', 'password_reset_tokens'),
          'expire' => 15,
          'throttle' => 120
      ]
    ],

But token are long enough for example:
 2130a06a427b25950aaa2d855f1e3ba52e8042a428b985dec175e2b190254607

And that makes the user hard to type it into a mobile app. How I can make the password reset token shorter and short lived as well in a laravel password broker?
I want the token to last for 15 minutes ans be a 4-digit number instead of a long string so the user can easily type it but also because it is short lived as well user will also security will not be compromized as well.
The shortness can be achieved via expire setting but what about the token???
How I can do that?

Why don't you go for clickable link rather just typing token?

No web interface to do so. Only app and rest these are the specs.

Even if you make it short (ex: rand(1000, 9999); ), we cannot assure you this security will not be compromized as well. What comes to my mind is creating a clickable link in email, setting a new password in the browser, and showing the success page with a proper success message (ex: Now you an log in to your app...). Then, the user can log in to the app after resetting it.

It's relatively simple to override the default token provider, but why would you do this? Creating a web UI for simple account administration would be trivial, and/or just register your URL with app install so the app opens instead of a web page when users click the link.

One quick tip that has nothing to do with your issue, instead of checking if the validation failed and throwing a ValidationException, just do Validator::validate(INPUT, RULES);, if it fails, it will automatically do what you are manually doing

Is your front a mobile app? (react native, ios, android, etc)? If so you could try deeplinking

Have not tried it but based on simple google search, you can "open" an app if you click a link. Then do your redirects

something like this: https://medium.com/swlh/creating-deep-links-in-react-native-f6680dd959a9
